# How to select duplicates by first order of appearance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking to select unique values from a SQL database but I want to make sure that I am selecting only the first duplicate in order of appearance (in my case - date in the hospital, intime col)

You can see the code below.
I am trying to take only the IDs of the first time the patients were hospitalized which correspond to the "intime" col.

I have no absolute way to check that by ordering as I did and by using groupby, SQL will in fact return the id in the same order.

Thank you very much.

```
WITH ccupatients AS
  (SELECT HADM_ID
  FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays` i
  WHERE first_careunit = 'CCU'
  ORDER BY intime)
SELECT hadm_id
FROM ccupatients
GROUP BY hadm_id
```

Comment: I'm using BigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` if your RDBMS supports it: this works by ranking records by increasing `intime` within groups of records having the same `ham_id`, and then filtering in the outer query on the top record per group:

```
SELECT hadm_id
FROM (
    SELECT hadm_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hadm_id ORDER BY intime) rn
    FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical`.icustays
    WHERE first_careunit = 'CCU'
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you RDBMS does not support window functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, another option is to use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT hadm_id
FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical`.icustays i
WHERE 
    first_careunit = 'CCU'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical`.icustays i1
        WHERE 
            i1.first_careunit = 'CCU'
            AND i1.hadm_id = i.hadm_id
            AND i1.intime < i.intime
    )
```

Comment: Welcome @EricYamga! Glad that it helped.